# Why does dropna not drop na?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

From my understanding, dropna for pandas in python drops rows with an empty entry.

```
import pandas as pd
the_data = pd.read_csv("EnzymeTrainingData.csv")
the_data.dropna(inplace = True)
seqs = the_data["protein_sequence"]
amino_numeros = seqs.apply(len)
hands = amino_numeros.apply(lambda n : float(n*(n + 1))/2)
the_pH = the_data["pH"]


additive = 14
x_train = []
for i in range(len(the_pH)):
    print(i)
    print(the_pH[i])
```

But for my code, it says at index 69:
KeyError: 69

Why is this? Is it because I am doing something wrong with the dropna? Or is it something else?

Comment: Try `.reset_index`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drop rows like that, pandas does not renumber the index.  If you drop the row at index 69, then there will be nothing at index 69.  Your `range` is going by row number, but the `the_pH[i]` notation does a lookup by index.

You can either redo the index, or you can use `iterrows` to iterate the rows one by one, or use `the_pH.iloc[i]` to go by row number.